# how to display array stored in jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I have information stored in array in jsonb column in postgres(9.5) database:

```
    {
        "status" : "NOK",
        "info" : [{
            "type" : "TYPE1",
            "error" : [],
            "values" : [-44.995882968879044, -32.84752217736367, -18.645252496214137, -5.917307355383778],
            "sources" : [{
                        "id" : "54374c62",
                        "type" : "regular",
                            "distance" : {
                                "to" : 0.9378531073446326,
                                "from" : 0.0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "algorithm" : "rel",
                }
            ]
         }
```

I want to display "values" and "algorithm" from "info as new columns. Here is my example query. Any help?

```
SELECT id,
 column_jsonb -> 'status' as status,
 column_jsonb -> 'info' -> 'value' as value,
 column_jsonb -> 'info' -> 'type' as type,
 column_jsonb -> 'info' -> 'algorithm' as algorithm

  FROM data.transaction
where id = '8db348e1-a8ec'
```

Comment: Please add expected result.

Comment: I expect: 
| ID | -44.99, (....)|TYPE1| rel |  

The problem is that I can't display information stored in array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements`

```
with the_table(id, column_jsonb ) as(
select  '8db348e1-a8ec'::text, '{"status" : "NOK",
    "info" : [{
    "type" : "TYPE1",
    "error" : [],
    "values" : [-44.995882968879044, -32.84752217736367, -18.645252496214137, -5.917307355383778],
    "sources" : [{
        "id" : "54374c62",
        "type" : "regular",
        "distance" : {
        "to" : 0.9378531073446326,
        "from" : 0.0
        }
        }
        ],
        "algorithm" : "rel"
    }
    ]
     }'::jsonb 
)

select 
the_table.id,
the_table.column_jsonb->'status',
j.value->'type',
j.value->'values',
j.value->'algorithm'
from the_table
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(column_jsonb -> 'info') as j
on true

where
the_table.id = '8db348e1-a8ec'
```

Note that if you have more than one element in `info` array, then you get duplicate results for same rows.